# Android Studio Giraffe canary not showing app logs

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I just downloaded Android Studio Giraffe canary and i think i am doing something wrong because it's all new for me after chipmunk version of Android studio. I tried to look for the logs for my debug app but it's only showing few unrelated app logs. I tried following things to make it work:-

- Kill and restart adb
- Delete .idea and .gradle folders
- Invalidate Cache
- Restart phone,Android studio,Windows
- Waited for hours for logs to comes up.

My log windows only shows these logs even i start and close app sevral times

```
--------- beginning of system
2023-03-30 17:05:16.927 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{1059c15 u0 Splash Screen com.elaxer.social.network EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5975 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:242 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6228 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:113 
2023-03-30 17:05:42.909 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{b75c4d7 u0 com.elaxer.social.network/com.elaxer.Navigation_Drawer EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5975 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:242 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6228 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:113 
2023-03-30 17:05:44.293 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{d3a392c u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5975 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:242 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6228 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:113 
2023-03-30 17:05:47.509 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{8210b94 u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5906 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6532 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130 
--------- beginning of main
2023-03-30 17:24:38.374 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{8210b94 u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5906 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6532 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130 
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (9765) for package com.example.demo ----------------------------
2023-03-30 17:57:49.306 USNET                   pid-9765                             E  USNET: appName: com.example.demo
2023-03-30 17:57:51.164 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{767abba u0 Splash Screen com.example.demo EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5975 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:242 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6228 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:113 
2023-03-30 17:59:28.975 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{2ef8602 u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5906 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6532 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130 
2023-03-30 17:59:28.977 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{6a9939b u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5906 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6532 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130 
2023-03-30 17:59:28.979 WindowManager           pid-1542                             E  win=Window{1dce323 u0 com.example.demo/example.demo.Navigation_Drawer} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5861 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5842 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5906 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6532 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130
```

From 10 times i only get actual logs only 1-2 times. I also using filters `package:mine` and `package:mine & level:debug`. I don't want to downgrade my Android studio version because it's work smooth for me than previous one. If i am doing something wrong please let me know.